# Clone a Linux ISO and use it to boot other computers with

Tags: boot

Ok so basically I have a Linux (Ubuntu 22.04.1) distribution with custom installs etc that I need to constantly clone to other new computers. I would like to do this by using a bootable USB and despite multiple searches and endless research I can't find anything to do what I need.

Comment: Which "Linux distribution" are you referring to? Add the name and its version into question (not into the comments)

Comment: Done :). qwertyuiop

Comment: I used `pinguy builder` to do this once - at least to create a bootable .iso clone of my server before I upgraded it. However, that was a 16.04 to 18.04 upgrade, and it looks like the s/w hasn't been updated in a while. Back then it worked though! https://sourceforge.net/projects/pinguy-os/files/ISO_Builder/

Comment: A search for "custom iso" will probably give you lots to work with.

Comment: Have you looked, many people who create their own distribution blog about how they did it, what tools they used (*often starting with a prior tool with them blogging about their own modifications & why it's better*). They usually modify their own system's then use the tool to create an ISO from it for others to download & benefit from their work.  I've seen many such articles/blogs, so I'd just use a search engine to find them (*I have no need for such a tool; Ubuntu doesn't need them, so only read the article & move on ... so would need to search for them myself if I required them*)

Comment: clonezilla, particularly if the targets are identical. but I think you mean customised Ubuntu installation bootable media.